# Restrict Calls, SMS and Data usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms, mdm

Can we restrict the below in iOS using objective-c or MDM (Mobile Device Management):

- Making outgoing calls
- Sending Messages (SMS)
- Data transfer (Data Usage)

In the survey we found that the below MDM providers claim to do so.

[TELUS mobile device management service](http://www.telus.com/en_CA/content/pdf/products/Security/Secure_Mobile_Device_Management.pdf)

*So is this possible with iOS?*

Answer (score 0):

the providers might be able to but from app side it isn't possible (at least not without jail breaking the phone)